# can we add divider into lightning component design on page builder

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, builder

is there any way to divide the section into the lightning component design on page builder. like **Set Component visibility** heading. I have many design attribute and want to make sections. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the Accordion component is what you're looking for:

[image]

Comment: No i'm not looking for this one i want section on design attribute on page builder.